How to bind to ComboBox.SelectedIndex using C++/WinRT and WinUI 3
I'm trying to bind an int to a ComboBox.SelectedIndex.  Binding to a TextBox is trivial, but it appears that some extra plumbing is needed for the SelectedIndex.  Here's the repro:
<!--MainWindow.xaml-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window
    x:Class="MiniEditor.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MiniEditor"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MiniEditor">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListView x:Name="MEList" Background="LightGoldenrodYellow" CanReorderItems="True" Height="600">
            <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="#" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Op" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:OpDatWRC">
                    <Grid x:Name="MEGrid">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{x:Bind Path=opnum}" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind Path=name}"/>
                        <!--<ComboBox Grid.Column="2"  Width="80" SelectedIndex="{x:Bind Path=op, Mode=TwoWay}">-->
                        <ComboBox Grid.Column="2"  Width="80" SelectedIndex="{x:Bind Path=op, Mode=OneTime}">
                            <x:String>&lt;</x:String>
                            <x:String>&gt;</x:String>
                            <x:String>=</x:String>
                            <x:String>|&lt;|</x:String>
                            <x:String>|&gt;|</x:String>
                            <x:String>|=|</x:String>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

//MainWindow.idl
namespace MiniEditor
{
    struct OpDatWRC
    {
        Int32 opnum;
        String name;
        Int32 op;
    };

    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass MainWindow : Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window
    {
        MainWindow();
        void AddOp(String name, Int32 op);
        Windows.Foundation.Collections.IVectorView<OpDatWRC> GetOps();
    }
}

//MainWindow.xaml.h
#pragma once

#include "MainWindow.g.h"

namespace winrt::MiniEditor::implementation
{
    struct MainWindow : MainWindowT<MainWindow>
    {
        MainWindow();

        void AddOp(hstring const& name, int32_t op);
        winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVectorView<winrt::MiniEditor::OpDatWRC> GetOps();
    private:
        winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<winrt::MiniEditor::OpDatWRC> ops{ winrt::single_threaded_observable_vector<winrt::MiniEditor::OpDatWRC>() };

    };
}

namespace winrt::MiniEditor::factory_implementation
{
    struct MainWindow : MainWindowT<MainWindow, implementation::MainWindow>
    {
    };
}

//MainWindow.xaml.cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "MainWindow.xaml.h"
#if __has_include("MainWindow.g.cpp")
#include "MainWindow.g.cpp"
#endif

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Microsoft::UI::Xaml;

namespace winrt::MiniEditor::implementation
{
    MainWindow::MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddOp(L"One", 0);
        AddOp(L"Two", 1);
        AddOp(L"Three", 2);

        MEList().ItemsSource(ops);
    }
    void MainWindow::AddOp(hstring const& name, int32_t op)
    {
        // Create an instance of OpDatWRC
        winrt::MiniEditor::OpDatWRC newItem;
        newItem.opnum = ops.Size();
        newItem.name = name;
        newItem.op = op;

        // Add the new item to the IObservableVector
        ops.Append(newItem);
    }
    winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVectorView<winrt::MiniEditor::OpDatWRC> MainWindow::GetOps()
    {
        return ops.GetView();
    }
}

As shown, the binding to the ComboBox.SelectedIndex is "OneTime" and everything compiles and runs.  However, when I switch to the desired "TwoWay" binding, I get the following compiler error:
C2064 term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

The error points to a line in MainWindow.xaml.g.hpp.  Here's the code:
            case 8: // MainWindow.xaml line 38
                {
                    auto targetElement = target.as<::winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::ComboBox>();
                    obj8 = targetElement;
                    obj8.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(::winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives::Selector::SelectedIndexProperty(),
                        [weakThis{ this->weak_from_this() }, this] (DependencyObject const& sender, DependencyProperty const& prop)
                        {
                            if (auto strongThis{ weakThis.lock() })
                            {
                                if (IsInitialized())
                                {
                                    // Update Two Way binding
                                    GetDataRoot().op(obj8.SelectedIndex()); //<= error is here
                                }
                            }
                        });
                }
                break;

What do I need to add to my code to fix this error?  Do I need to explicitly define a setter for op?

For OneWay and TwoWay bindings, dynamic changes to the source don't automatically propagate to the target without providing some support from the source. You must implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on the source object. Refer to the Doc:Binding.Mode Property

Do you have put the full reproducing project somewhere so it's easier to test?

@Jeaninez-MSFT Oh, how I wish your link pointed to C++/WinRT code for WinUI 3.  While it's possible to figure out how to make C++/CX code for UWP work with the new technology, there are enough changes to make this quite difficult for those of us who have little enough knowledge to be asking a question like this.  Do I just have to make OpDatWRC::op a property that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, or do I have to make OpDatWRC a runtime class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged?

@SimonMourier Thanks for your interest. I created a public repository on github: https://github.com/dr-eck/MiniEditor

You can't databind two ways with a simple struct's field, you need a WinRT property (declared as a property in an .idl)

@SimonMourier Thanks.  Does this mean that I must convert OpDatWRC to a runtime class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged and make all of the fields properties?

That's exactly that

Thanks to @SimonMourier, I have working code.  Here's modified portion of the .idl:
    runtimeclass OpDatWRC : Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        OpDatWRC();
        Int32 opnum;
        String name;
        Int32 op;
    };

Same for the .h:
// OpDatWRC.h
#pragma once
#include "OpDatWRC.g.h"

namespace winrt::MiniEditor::implementation
{
    struct OpDatWRC : OpDatWRCT<OpDatWRC>
    {
        OpDatWRC() : m_opnum(0), m_name(L"BLANK"), m_op(0) {}

        int32_t opnum() { return m_opnum; }
        void opnum(int32_t value);
        hstring name() { return m_name; }
        void name(hstring const& value);
        int32_t op() { return m_op; }
        void op(int32_t value);
        winrt::event_token PropertyChanged(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler const& handler);
        void PropertyChanged(winrt::event_token const& token) noexcept;
    private:
        int m_opnum;
        hstring m_name;
        int m_op;
        winrt::event<Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler> m_propertyChanged;
    };
}
namespace winrt::MiniEditor::factory_implementation
{
    struct OpDatWRC : OpDatWRCT<OpDatWRC, implementation::OpDatWRC>
    {
    };
}

and .cpp:
// OpDatWRC.cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "OpDatWRC.h"
#include "OpDatWRC.g.cpp"

namespace winrt::MiniEditor::implementation
{
    void OpDatWRC::opnum(int32_t value)
    {
        if (m_opnum != value)
        {
            m_opnum = value;
            m_propertyChanged(*this, Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs{ L"Opnum" });
        }
    }
    void OpDatWRC::name(hstring const& value)
    {
        if (m_name != value)
        {
            m_name = value;
            m_propertyChanged(*this, Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs{ L"Name" });
        }
    }
    void OpDatWRC::op(int32_t value)
    {
        if (m_op != value)
        {
            m_op = value;
            m_propertyChanged(*this, Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs{ L"Op" });
        }
    }
    winrt::event_token OpDatWRC::PropertyChanged(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler const& handler)
    {
        return m_propertyChanged.add(handler);
    }
    void OpDatWRC::PropertyChanged(winrt::event_token const& token) noexcept
    {
        m_propertyChanged.remove(token);
    }
}

Finally, here's the updated XAML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window
    x:Class="MiniEditor.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MiniEditor"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MiniEditor">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListView x:Name="MEList" Background="LightGoldenrodYellow" CanReorderItems="True" Height="600">
            <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="#" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Op" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:OpDatWRC">
                    <Grid x:Name="MEGrid">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{x:Bind Path=opnum}" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind Path=name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        <ComboBox Grid.Column="2"  Width="80" SelectedIndex="{x:Bind Path=op, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <!--<ComboBox Grid.Column="2"  Width="80" SelectedIndex="{x:Bind Path=op, Mode=OneTime}">-->
                            <x:String>&lt;</x:String>
                            <x:String>&gt;</x:String>
                            <x:String>=</x:String>
                            <x:String>|&lt;|</x:String>
                            <x:String>|&gt;|</x:String>
                            <x:String>|=|</x:String>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

The entire solution is in https://github.com/dr-eck/MiniEditor  As a bonus, working code for the WinUI 3 version of the Bookstore example is added.  The main trick for that code was changing Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged to Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged.
